# bypass IIS xml file settings at file/folder level

Tags: iis

Our site is currently set to pass all files with the xml file extension through the asp.net worker process because all the xml files on the site at the moment are generated dynamically on being hit, by writing the output directly into the response stream.

However we now have a requirement to add a file which is much larger and takes several minutes to generate in this way. I wrote a console app to generate the file and set it to run nightly, but because of the global IIS setting directing xml files to run through asp_wp, it's not being served properly.

I can't seem to find a way to make an exemption for the treatment of a single file in the IIS settings. Is there any other way we can do it?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible for a single file, but you can do it for a whole folder.

You simply place a `web.config` file in the folder in question and configure the settings you need there.

Comment: What settings would I use in web.config to set IIS to ignore this file?

Comment: @Matt: Use the IIS manager tools to generate the web.config on a test or development machine, then look in the web.config to see what entries are there. This is easier than looking up a reference.